# can't recreate the Twitter bootstrap popover demo on jsfiddle.net

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter has a JavaScript plugin that makes little popovers (scroll over an element, and a box pops up providing additional information).  This plugin also uses the bootstrap-twipsy.js file.

There's a demo here [http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html](http://Twitter%20Bootstrap%20JS) if you scroll down to the Popovers demo.

I've copied the code for the demo at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/mT76T/16/

and I also included the necessary files (bootstrap-popver.js and bootstrap-twipsy.js) but the popovers not working when I scroll over.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

This is the html

```
<a href="#" class="btn danger" rel="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A title">hover for popover</a>
```

and this is the jquery function i added to get the popover to show

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#blob').popover('show');
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead, example here http://jsfiddle.net/mT76T/17/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $(function () {
                $("#blob").popover({
                offset: 10
                    })

})
});
```

Comment: Unless Im mistaken the inner function there isnt necessary. Any reason you chose to add it?

Here is an updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/bradleygriffith/mT76T/1926/

Answer (score 10):

**You don't need to call** `$('#blob').popover('show')`. That is how you would manually trigger the popover.

**To simply initialize the popover**, you should instead call `$('#blob').popover()`, with any options passed in that you'd like.

You can see it working in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mT76T/18/

*Pro tip: instead of wrapping everything in a document ready function call, you can simply use JSFiddle's built-in `onDomReady` from the dropdown. Saves some time.*